# SSH -X not working for specific application

Tags: ssh, x

At my job, we have a number of compute servers, running linux. I want to run my software on it with a GUI from a windows system. Due to the nature of the job, VNC is not an option, and it has to use SSH.

This works fine for all applications but one (ANSYS HFSS). In other software I can just start up the software after connecting with SSH, and it will open a window on my local windows computer. However, with HFSS, it will either

- display the splash screen and when that disappears nothing happens (the program is still running when I check with htop, and it uses a few % CPU)
- Not do anything at all
- If I start the program with a file path to load, it will show me the GUI, and then crash

I'm using mobaXterm on the windows system.

Comment: ANSYS HFSS seems to need a real graphics card.

Comment: @meuh HFSS does run when launched within a linux command line, as is demonstrated by the fact that my colleagues seem to be able to run it just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer this question for anyone who runs into this...
My issue was to do with MobaXterm (and the default X server). There is some issue in the xserver that mobaXterm uses that causes the GUI to crash when closing a message window.

When I use a different Xserver (VcXserv) this issue does not occur. (note however that a lot of the HFSS 3D rendering doesn't work, but that is not much of an issue to me).